# How to combine XPATH "select //td/text() or //td/p/text()" into one sentence?

Tags: xpath, path-combine

I want to select text() within each row in the following HTML. However, the text I want is either in the **td** element or the **p** element, so I have to write two statements to ensure each row is selected.

How do I combine the two statements into one?

XPATH:

```
//table/tr/td[not(p)]/text() | //table/tr/td/p/text()
```

With the result desired:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Original html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>4
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want something like this:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td//text()[normalize-space()]
```

All non-whitespace-only text nodes one or more levels deep in the `//table/tr/td` will be found.